# C# WebBrowser.Navigate Issue

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control, directory

I have an XML file stored in the DEBUG folder inside the BIN Folder of my Application (BIN\DEBUG\File.xml)

When i call WebBrowser1.Navigate("File.xml");

It doesn't update the view with the display of the file. I know it's something to do with it not locating the file due to the folder location being incorrect. The file has to be accessed from this folder location.

Help appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have WebBrowser1.AllowNavigation set to true? Have you tried:

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "File.xml"));
```

Comment: Yes, you need to specify a fully-qualified path here. You can also use Process Monitor or FileMon to watch exactly where the WebBrowser control is *attempting* to load the file from.

Answer (score 0):

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\File.xml");
```

This is what I use, if the directory hasn't been changed, ofcourse. :)